# Can't use equal operator

Tags: python-3.6

When I try a '=' operator to get python to compare the values of arguments to user input, it tells me it just doesn't work with a Syntax Error.

For whatever reason, changing all equal signs to the 'is' operator fixes this error. Though I feel like this is a good way to make my program incredibly buggy instead of a proper fix.

```
def movePieces1(initialSpot,finalSpot):
    initialSpot = input('Move which piece?: ').upper()
    finalSpot = input('To which place?: ').upper()
    if initialSpot = 'A1' and finalSpot = row1[0] or row1[2,5]:
        print('Invalid Move')

    elif initialSpot = 'A2' and finalSpot = row1[1] or row1[3,5]:
            print('Invalid Move')
```

Error:

> File "pown-chess.py", line 81
>       if initialSpot = 'A1' and finalSpot = row1[0] or row1[2,5]:
>                      ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Use `==` to compare values. `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for equality you need to use `==`.

`=` assigns a name to a value.

Change it to something like this:

```
def movePieces1(initialSpot,finalSpot):
    initialSpot = input('Move which piece?: ').upper()
    finalSpot = input('To which place?: ').upper()
    if initialSpot == 'A1' and finalSpot == row1[0] or row1[2,5]:
        print('Invalid Move')

    elif initialSpot == 'A2' and finalSpot == row1[1] or row1[3,5]:
            print('Invalid Move')
```